# Jquery pie chart issue

Tags: php, jquery, flot, pie-chart

"I used simple jquery piechart code.Here pie chart is not showing me for first request after refresh the page it showing pie chart."Below is my code for it.

```
    <?php 
    $total_advanced = 0;
    $total_proficient = 0;
    $total_basic = 0;
    $total_belowbasic = 0;
    $total_farbelow = 0;
    $total_noscore = 0;
    ?>
    <div id="proficiency_pie<?php echo $widget->id;?>" style="width: auto; min-width: 150px; height: 150px;"></div>
    <script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode(array(
        array( 'label'=>"Advanced",  'data'=>$total_advanced, 'color'=>'#007F5B'),
        array( 'label'=>"Proficient",  'data'=>$total_proficient, 'color'=>'#00CB95'),
        array( 'label'=>"Basic",  'data'=>$total_basic, 'color'=>'#FFB800'),
        array( 'label'=>"Below Basic",  'data'=>$total_belowbasic, 'color'=>'#F9CF60'),
        array( 'label'=>"Far Below",  'data'=>$total_farbelow, 'color'=>'#F17F71'),
        array( 'label'=>"No Score",  'data'=>$total_noscore, 'color'=>'#EEEEEE'),
    )); ?>;
    $(function(){
        try {
            $.plot($("#proficiency_pie<?php echo $widget->id;?>"), data,
            {
                series: {
                    pie: {
                        show: true
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch ($e) {}
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Just a recommendation, tag `php` aswell to your question to get more attention from that direction

Comment: I believe you are using `FLOT` library ..it would be great if you tag it with `flot`